# Find genes with good correlation from a correlation matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have matrix file which is basically a spearman correlation matrix between genes across various cell type. So now Im trying to find out which set of genes or group of genes whose correlation value is lets say greater than 0.6 if I set that as my threshold. How can I do that? I'm posting a subset of my data. It's a 502 x 502 matrix.

```
        ACTL6B   ACTR5   ACTR6
ACTL6B  1        0.6        -0.4
ACTR5   0.4        1        -0.3
ACTR6  -0.4      -0.3         1
```

So I don't want correlation between same set of genes which would be 1. I want another comparison. Like, lets say, `ACTL6B` and `ACTR5` whose correlation is 0.6. I would like to keep those values and genes.

Comment: Why the correlations between ACTR5 and ACTL6B are different?

Comment: "correlations between ACTR5 and ACTL6B are different?" because their FPKM values that is normalised gene expression is different, secondly both of them may not be expressed together one may be antagonistic  to to other

Comment: @SinanÜnür sorry for the tag it was not intended i was suppose to tag R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
mat <- cor(longley)  # example 7 x 7 correlation matrix

# Find indices of correlations greater than 0.6
idx <- which(mat > 0.6 & lower.tri(mat), arr.ind = TRUE)

# names of the resulting variables
cbind(rownames(idx), colnames(mat)[idx[, 2]])
```

Due to `lower.tri` all values on the diagonal and in the upper matrix are ignored.

The result:

```
      [,1]         [,2]          
 [1,] "GNP"        "GNP.deflator"
 [2,] "Unemployed" "GNP.deflator"
 [3,] "Population" "GNP.deflator"
 [4,] "Year"       "GNP.deflator"
 [5,] "Employed"   "GNP.deflator"
 [6,] "Unemployed" "GNP"         
 [7,] "Population" "GNP"         
 [8,] "Year"       "GNP"         
 [9,] "Employed"   "GNP"         
[10,] "Population" "Unemployed"  
[11,] "Year"       "Unemployed"  
[12,] "Year"       "Population"  
[13,] "Employed"   "Population"  
[14,] "Employed"   "Year"
```

Comment: Should that be `idx <- which(abs(mat) > 0.6 & lower.tri(mat), arr.ind = TRUE)` as a large negative value (e.g., -0.7) shows a correlation, just a negative correlation?

Comment: @Lyngbakr This decision depends on the OP's goal. However, your proposal is correct.

Comment: thank you for your reply since i can;t upvote so as i have not reached 15 reputation but thank you very much...I will try the code

Comment: Meanwhile Im getting this error "Error in abs(M) > 0.6 & lower.tri(mat) : non-conformable arrays"

Comment: You're mixing up matrix names. Is your matrix called `M` or `mat`? Because you're using both names...